# How to convert Jess (.jar files) libraries to .dex file, or run java class files on Android?

Tags: java, android, jess, terminal-ide

I am trying to run Jess on Terminal IDE (android), but when I try to run the following:

```
terminal++@192.168.0.102:~/sdcard/myJess$ dx --dex --output=jess.dex Jess71p2/lib/jess.jar
```

I get the message:

```
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably produced by a broken compiler.)
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably produced by a broken compiler.)
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably produced by a broken compiler.)
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably produced by a broken compiler.)
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably produced by a broken compiler.)

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.HashMap.makeTable(HashMap.java:569)
    at java.util.HashMap.doubleCapacity(HashMap.java:589)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:419)
    at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpec.intern(RegisterSpec.java:71)
    at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpec.makeLocalOptional(RegisterSpec.java:124)
    at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpec.withReg(RegisterSpec.java:482)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaRenamer$BlockRenamer$RenamingMapper.map(SsaRenamer.java:325)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.RegisterMapper.map(RegisterMapper.java:53)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.NormalSsaInsn.mapSourceRegisters(NormalSsaInsn.java:43)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaRenamer$BlockRenamer.visitNonMoveInsn(SsaRenamer.java:555)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.NormalSsaInsn.accept(NormalSsaInsn.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaBasicBlock.forEachInsn(SsaBasicBlock.java:957)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaRenamer$BlockRenamer.process(SsaRenamer.java:341)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaRenamer$1.visitBlock(SsaRenamer.java:146)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.forEachBlockDepthFirstDom(SsaMethod.java:787)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaRenamer.run(SsaRenamer.java:143)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:53)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:100)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:74)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:269)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:299)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:278)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:229)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:250)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:136)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:113)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:247)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:183)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:139)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:120)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:89)
    at com.spartacusrex.spartacuside.external.dx.main(dx.java:14)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried other approaches, like connecting via ssh to other machine, but it is not available and fast as local.
Does anyone know a solution or other method?

Answer (score 1):

Jess 7 is not compatible with Android. Jess 8, which will be released any day now, will be. So keep an eye on www.jessrules.com .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  `--no-strict` to `dx` options, and if you are facing OutOfMemory Exception,  you should **edit** your `dx` script and extend the memory range :

```
dalvikvm -Xss262912 -Xmx500M -cp $APK com.spartacusrex.spartacuside.external.dx $@
```

Change the `-Xmx500M` to your required memory

> That is, until you stop receiving OOM exception.

For me ,while dexing tools.jar from JDK's tools.jar, it's limit was `-Xmx900M` after which,  no more memory could be allocated because my phone had around 900-990MBs free.

- The next step after dexing the class files is to repack any remaining resource file from your jess.jar because dex file has no resources.
- Observe the contents of that `jar` file with `java` command or with winrar or any file explorer and find resources folder(s). You'll probably find more than one such `resources` folders, extract all of those.
- Make sure that your dex file has name `classes.dex` then repack all files together in a new jess_for_android.jar, keep all the resources in the same directory tree as they were in original jess.jar file
- Lastly, when you try to use it, use `dalvikvm` command , not the `java` or you will(possibly)
  get errors :

  ```
  dalvikvm -cp path_To_your_repacked_jar Main_className $@
  ```

> memory options -Xss and -Xmx are optional.

Hope this helps, If you get Jess tool working,  please provide a link to it.